# Grid snapping not working in Perspective mode

Tags: snapping

If I select my model, turn on Increment snapping and select 'Absolute Grid', then the object will only snap in an orthographic view and not in perspective. any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's possible to do the way you want

Comment: It was possible, it was due to broken preferences. All I did was to reset back to factory default